# WAMP 2.0i server

Tags: mysql, windows, phpmyadmin

i just installed the WAMP 2.0i server and it seems to be working.
but when i open PhpMyAdmin in the localhost the following error occurs...

"***Error
MySQL said:

 #1045 - Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
phpMyAdmin tried to connect to the MySQL server, and the server rejected the connection. You should check the host, username and password in your configuration and make sure that they correspond to the information given by the administrator of the MySQL server.***"

what should i do to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Your password for user root is not correct.This is what error says.

Check [this](http://en.kioskea.net/faq/673-phpmyadmin-access-denied-for-user-root-localhost) article.